# Initialize and scope a generic abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code

```
            var dataCollection;
            if (ViewBag.WageType.ToLower() == "perm")
            {
                dataCollection = ViewBag.PermWageIndex;
            }
            else if(ViewBag.WageType.ToLower() == "trial")
            {
                dataCollection = ViewBag.TrialWageIndex;
            }
```

The return type can be `AbstractClass<Concrete1>` or `AbstractClass<Concrete2>`. I must initialize the var at declaration.  But, this means I lose the scope I desire.  How can I modify this code to allow dynamic dataCollections without depending on the ViewBag?

Comment: Can't you make the method (or the containing class) generic? And it's hard to give advice with so little context. What is `AbstractClass`? Is there some relation between `Concrete1` and `Concrete2`? How is the result going to be used?

Comment: @svick - I'd have to explain quite a bit of design to answer those questions.  I am hoping this is enough information to solve the problem.  It may not be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to make `AbstractClass<>` implement the interface `IAbstractClass` and then make that the common type.

Whether this will work or not depends exactly which members the return type needs to access.  Obviously, it won't be able to refer to any of the generically typed members, but that wouldn't make much sense anyway, since I'm assuming the consumer shouldn't know what the generic parameter is anyway.

Comment: +1 Ahh, of course you are right. The consumer (view) should not handle the problem, rather the controller. That makes it easy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The only way solving this is by providing a base class or interface which is inherited/implemented by `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` so you can declare `dataCollection` as `AbstractClass<ISomething>`.

Var is not dynamic typing it is resolved at compile time. Therefore you can not declare a variable without assignment (`var x;`) because the compiler can not infer the type.

You can fall back to `object` or `dynamic` however you loose any type safety if you do so.